# SSRS Site URL from ReportServer database using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Is it possible to get the SSRS Site URL from the ReportServer database?

The `ReportServer.ConfigurationInfo` returns a blank URL, but does return the site name. It feels like the Reports Service should know about the database, not the other way around - so I expect not.

Would be useful to know, for reporting, auditing, management, etc. I am using to periodically clean out stale subscription emails, etc. across multiple servers / databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the URLs are stored in the registry with the key names `RSVirtualRootApplication` and `RSVirtualRootServer` in the following path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS{Version Number}.{InstanceName}\Setup
```

So, if you're running a 2012 instance, with the default instance name, then the penultimate path would be `MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER`.

Though you *can* inspect the registry using T-SQL, I would personally advise against it, and use a different method; such as Powershell.